# Returning an object from a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object, prototype, javascript-objects

I have a function that returns an object in javascript. The objects returned are instances of a "messagePack" that I want to send to the server. Each messagePack will be different. E.g.:

```
    function someFunc() {
        return {
            name: "chatMessage",
            time: Date.now(),
            data: "yooo hoooo",
            hash: hashFunc()               
        }
    }
```

I then create a create a messagePack and add it to an array:

```
    var messagePack = someFunc();

    msgArray.push(messagePack)
```

Is this ok? Should I be creating a constructor function for message pack and using the new keyword? I've seen this done in as similar situation but I can't see why what I'm doing wont work.

Comment: note: hash is not being used for security.

Comment: Better to create a constructor function , so that you can set new `name` and `data` for every new instance

Comment: This seems like a question that is either entirely opinion based or could be reworked to make it on-topic for the Code Review Stackexchange.

Comment: @suzo you don't need a constructor or new, the object returned by the function will always be a new instance of a literal object. You can still pass arguments to the someFunc() function if you want to change name or data.

Comment: And indeed I am passing arguments to someFunc(). Can a moderator move this please if it is incorrectly categorised.

Comment: @Booster2ooo Yes I agree, there's nothing wrong in that, but I personally prefer a constructor function to a factory pattern especially when we have functions on the object.

Comment: Strange the constructor pattern is very confusing for me and this just seems right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a factory pattern, it's perfectly correct. You don't need to use a constructor.

Comment: To clarify, here I am creating a "new Object" every time I return the literal right? So there's no need for a constructor.

Comment: That's right, each call to someFunc() will return a new literal object. Factories are a good way to work, it avoids the use of `this` which can be confusing some times. Douglas Crockford made a really good speech about javascript functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM (at 1:00:00 he covers constructors and inheritance but the whole speech is interesting)

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is useful, when youve got multiple objects containing the same data, e. g. functions or constants. As you dont have this repeatin data ( i believe) , you dont need them. if youve got repeating data, you could do this:

```
var message_prot={
     name: "chatMessage",
        time: Date.now(),
        data: "yooo hoooo",
        hash: false
};

function somefunc(){
  a=Object.create(message_prot);
  a.name="Hi";
  a.hash=hashfunc();
  return a;
 }
```

Comment: Afaik, this is still a factory, not a constructor function. A constructor will take advantage of `this`, doesn't return an object but `this` and must be called with `new`

Comment: @Booster2ooo: but techincally no difference to a constructor ( output, internal design)

Comment: indeed, that's why the anwser to Your Friend---A Rat is "no", you can do it without using an "actual" constructor.

Comment: may read my answer again. i say that his solution is working perfeclty.